# Unable to register with GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm trying to initialize SNS Push Services based on GCM Push Services on my Android app. The app was working great on my former device, Samsung Galaxy S5. Recently, I've changed my phone to Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime. On the first time I've installed it on my new phone I've got this error log:

```
E/GCMTokenHelper: Unable to register with GCM. MAIN_THREAD
                                                             java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.GCMTokenHelper.updateGCMToken(GCMTokenHelper.java:79)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager.registerDevice(PushManager.java:202)
                                                                 at com.intap.appme.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:237)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

These are the lines contains errors mentioned in the log:

GCMTokenHelper.java:79

```
synchronized
public void updateGCMToken() {
    String newDeviceToken;
    // GCM throws a NullPointerException in some failure cases.
    try {
        /* This is 79 line which gives me error -> */ newDeviceToken = instanceID.getToken(gcmSenderID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
    } catch (final Exception re) {
        final String error = "Unable to register with GCM. " + re.getMessage();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, error, re);
        for (GCMTokenUpdateObserver observer : updateObservers) {
            observer.onGCMTokenUpdateFailed(re);
        }
        return;
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Current GCM Device Token:" + newDeviceToken);

    final boolean didTokenChange = !newDeviceToken.equals(deviceToken);
    if (didTokenChange) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GCM Device Token changed from: " + deviceToken);
        deviceToken = newDeviceToken;
        sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putString(SHARED_PREFS_KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN, deviceToken)
            .apply();
    }
    for (GCMTokenUpdateObserver observer : updateObservers) {
        observer.onGCMTokenUpdate(deviceToken, didTokenChange);
    }
}
```

PushManager.java:202

```
public void registerDevice() {
    // Updates the GCM token, which triggers {@link #onGCMTokenUpdate(String,boolean)} to create the platform
    // arn set push enabled, and re-subscribe to any previously subscribed topics.
    /* This is line 202 which gives me error -> */ gcmTokenHelper.updateGCMToken();
}
```

HomeActivity.java:237

```
final PushManager pushManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getPushManager();

    pushManager.registerDevice();
```

What can I do? On my former device it worked well, but now I get errors when I try to register my device to GCM Push Services.